# Have chart as parameter in function

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a function in which I want to pass a chart object as a parameter but I am not able to do so. I am getting the below message while calling the function

`runtime error 438: Object does not support this property or method.`

Below is the set of code I am working on.

```
Sub testppt()

changeChart (Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes(1).Chart)
changeChart (Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(5).Shapes(1).Chart)
changeChart (Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(6).Shapes(1).Chart)
changeChart (Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(7).Shapes(1).Chart)
changeChart (Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(8).Shapes(1).Chart)

End Sub

Function changeChart(chartToChange As Object)
Dim curSeries As Object
Dim curPoint As Object

For Each curSeries In chartToChange.SeriesCollection
    With curSeries
        For Each curPoint In .Points
            If curPoint.DataLabel.Text < 0 Then
                curPoint.DataLabel.Text = curPoint.DataLabel.Text * (-1)
            End If
            If curPoint.DataLabel.Text < 20 Then
                curPoint.DataLabel.Delete
            End If
        Next
    End With
Next

End Function
```

Comment: remove parentheses: `changeChart Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes(1).Chart` or use `Call` keyword: `Call changeChart (Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes(1).Chart)`

Comment: thanks for the answer, I am able to enter in the function now :)

Comment: one of the irritating things about VBA syntax ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I metnioned in comments, remove parentheses:

```
Sub testppt()
    changeChart Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes(1).Chart
    changeChart Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(5).Shapes(1).Chart
    changeChart Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(6).Shapes(1).Chart
    changeChart Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(7).Shapes(1).Chart
    changeChart Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(8).Shapes(1).Chart
End Sub
```

or use `Call` keyword:

```
Sub testppt()
    Call changeChart(Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes(1).Chart)
    Call changeChart(Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(5).Shapes(1).Chart)
    Call changeChart(Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(6).Shapes(1).Chart)
    Call changeChart(Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(7).Shapes(1).Chart)
    Call changeChart(Application.ActivePresentation.Slides(8).Shapes(1).Chart)
End Sub
```